# How to load .Rprofile and .Renviron files from an existing R project in JupyterLab?

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, rprofile

I currently have an R project that I created in Rstudio. For this project I created an .Rprofile file. Lately, I've been using JupyterLab to test things, and while I set the same working directory (`setwd("~/path/to/project")`) as the same as the project I created in RStudio, the R session in JupyterLab doesn't read the project's .Rprofile.

How can share a project's .Rprofile and .Renviron files between RStudio and JupyterLab?

Comment: Once you call `setwd` it’s already too late: the session has already started and read the configuration files *at that time*. You’ll need to find a way in Jupyter of *starting* your R session in the correct project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the files manually, e.g. in your first Jupyter cell:

```
source("/path/to/.Rprofile")
readRenviron("/path/to/.Renviron")
```